# FTP error:- The given path's format is not supported

Tags: windows, ftp

This is not a programmers questions. I have an application that I am using, and through that I can connect to an FTP, when I try to copy down a file I get FTP error: The given path's format is not supported.

However what is stranger is that my co-worker who is using the same application when they connect to the FTP site through the application installed on their PC they do not get the same error when they copy down a file. So I don't think the error is related to the code, but maybe to the setup to my PC?

Comment: simply the other user could have the application in their pc related to the file downloaded and u may not have that.. Any way post this on superuser

Comment: can you paste the exact filename please?